# How to send environment variables using curl

Tags: curl, environment-variables

I am trying to use slack to notify when a build is complete or if a build fails on GitlabCI. What I also wanna be able to do is append a predefined environment variable $GITLAB_CI_COMMIT_TITLE so along with the build  notification I also know which build with what commit has completed/failed

In short,

**This works**

```
"curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{\"text\":\" Client Staging build complete. \n\"}'
https://hooks.slack.com/services/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"
```

**But this doesnt**

```
"curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data-binary '{
      "'"$CI_COMMIT_TITLE"'" \n\"}'
```

The second command works, but it doesnt export the value of the variable, I just see '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE' in the slack notification.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled across the same problem and it seems that the following solution works:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json'
     --data '{"text": " '"$CI_COMMIT_TITLE"' "}'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ghosts anwser is working for me too, but wanted to clarify the space between the " and ' are essential for getting it working.

I tried "'"${CI_COMMIT_TITLE}"'" and kept getting http 500 errors so the space seems to be mandatory.