# Calling curl with an environment variable within the parameters

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to execute a curl command using an environment variable.

```
curl -u {user}: -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"my-var": " '"$ENV_VAR"' "}' https://url
```

However, this is not correctly fetching the output of `$ENV_VAR`, and instead passes in the string `$ENV_VAR`

The above implementation was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106956/how-to-send-environment-variables-using-curl).

How do I correctly pass the value of the environment variable into the curl command?

Comment: @P.... OP writes his variable between double-quotes and [it should work just fine](https://ideone.com/9LB6OV) (although the extra spaces should probably be removed).

Comment: Hard to see what else it could be though, if the variable was undefined in this context it would simply show up as en empty string, not as `$ENV_VAR`. @fuzzi, are you really sure you did use the exact quoting style you posted?

Comment: Thanks @P.... in all 3 of your examples, the value of the variable was echoed in all 3 of those echo commands.

Comment: @Aaron I removed the extra spaces, and this worked! The link I had above contained an answer that stated the spaces were essential.  If you'd like to post an Answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I mentioned removing the extra spaces because it produced `'{"my-var": " foo "}'` as seen in my ideone link but there's no way it fixed your variable appearing as `$ENV_VAR`. I wouldn't know how to answer the question you posted